# Is there a way to join 2 Indexes in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, kibana, dashboard

I'm trying to join 2 index in ES where I need to merge few columns of Index 1 and Index 2 respectively. I don't want to waste more time on recreating the index with the columns i wanted because my use case tends to change rapidly. Is there a way to query ES or in Kibana dashboard to visualize the content.?

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [Kibi](https://siren.solutions/kibi), which allows "Joins (Filters) across Elasticsearch indexes".

Comment: Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the Timelion plugin.

Check it out: https://www.elastic.co/blog/timelion-timeline